# Putting Win32 resources in a single .exe or use MUI satellite DLLs, performance difference?

Tags: windows, winapi, localization

I am in the process of updating a legacy Win32 application. This application supports 10 different GUI languages. Since Windows Vista it has become possible to use .mui files. The .mui languages files are handled and loaded automatically by the Windows resource loader.

The MSDN site list the following options:

**Use of a Single Language in a Resource DLL (MUI Resource Technology)**
A standard satellite DLL resource implementation is used by many Microsoft applications. In this case, a core executable file is used for the MUI application and one resource DLL is created for each supported language. Use of a satellite DLL applies to applications that run on any Windows operating system. As described in MUI Resource Management, the MUI resource technology supports a variation on the standard satellite DLL implementation.

**Use of Multiple Languages in a Resource DLL**
You can choose to create one core executable file for your MUI application and one resource DLL for the resources associated with supported languages. Copies of the same resource identifier are defined in the base language resource file (.rc extension) under different language tags for all supported languages.

**Question 1**
Would there be a (noticeable) performance difference in using a single .exe with all language resources or a satellite DLL per language?

**Question 2**
Any other general remarks why one of both options would be better?

Comment: The modules are mapped only once. So even if there is a (noticeable) performance impact, I very much doubt, that it matters. What does matter, though, is authoring and deployment. Segregating different languages into different modules certainly makes managing those resources (as in project management) and deploying updates a lot easier. Besides that, if you cram all languages into a single module, you have to map that single module into your process, wasting potentially crucial address space. Especially true with 32-bit applications.

Comment: It slows down a cold start, the OS needs to find one more file.  50 milliseconds is a decent guess for a spindle drive.  Use it when you need to, having to conserve address space or supporting installable language packs is not very common.